# How to hide background of dialogue when it is opened?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi all i have displayed a dialog box using this code

```
$(function(){
      $('#saveandcontinue').click(function(){   
           $('#savedialog').show("slow");          
        });
         $('#close24').click(function(){
            $('#savedialog').hide("slow");
        });
         $('#cnl24').click(function(){
            $('#savedialog').hide("slow");
        });
    });
```

here is my css

```
.pop1{
    border-top:10px solid #CCCCCC;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
    border: 30px solid #666666;
   height:300px;
   position:fixed;
   top:30%;
   left:30%;
    }
```

now i want to hide the backgound of this dialog. So how can i do this.Please help
here you can see my dialog box is not shown properly beacause of mys site creates problem in
background - http://screencast.com/t/oDRcqf3knCtz
and here you can see actual scrreen shot - http://screencast.com/t/Jvr82PYu8

Answer (score 0):

try to set `z-index` to your dialog box

```
#savedialog
{
  z-index:10; // any integer no. will help your dialog to be on top of the stack
}
```

Look at here http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Hope it would help you!

Comment: any reference page link or create fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/, will help me to find out your problem.